# wrong query output when using where and having in the same SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select CURRENCY.currencyname, currency.currencysymbol, COUNTRYNAME.currencycode, 
       currency.exchangerate
from CURRENCY,COUNTRYNAME
where currency.currencycode=COUNTRYNAME.currencycode
having currency.exchangerate >= max(currency.exchangerate)
group by CURRENCY.currencyname, currency.currencysymbol, 
         COUNTRYNAME.currencycode, currency.exchangerate;
```

This is the output I am getting and I know is wrong because I am trying to only display the maximum exchange rate that will be . So any help to resolve this query will be very appreciate. I am oracle sql developer

```
CURRENCYNAME         CURRENCYSYMBOL       CURRENCYCODE EXCHANGERATE
-------------------- -------------------- ------------ ------------
British Pound        £                    GBP                     1,
US Dollar            $                    USD                1.9626 ,
Danish Krone         kr                   DKK                9.9918 ,
Malaysian Ringgit    RM                   MYR               6.35392 ,
Euro                 €                    EUR               1.34076 ,
Indian Rupee         Rs                   INR               77.3265 ,
Japanese Yen         ¥                    JPY               209.881,
```

Comment: What are you supposed to do??

Comment: with _trying to display_ it is doing just what it does in the select ..

Comment: what about selecting the `max(currency.exchangerate)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT CURRENCY.currencyname, currency.currencysymbol, 
       COUNTRYNAME.currencycode, MAX(currency.exchangerate) as ExchangeRate
FROM CURRENCY
INNER JOIN COUNTRYNAME ON COUNTRYNAME.currencycode = currency.currencycode
GROUP BY CURRENCY.currencyname, currency.currencysymbol, COUNTRYNAME.currencycode;
```

Answer (score 0):

About your query...

`1`. You cannot compare the MAX (aggregate) value against the base value within the same query level. You can use a derived table (aka "subquery"), e.g.

```
    select c.currencyname, c.currencysymbol, n.currencycode, c.exchangerate
    from CURRENCY c
    join COUNTRYNAME n on c.currencycode=n.currencycode
    where c.exchangerate = (select max(exchangerate) from currency)
```

`2`. You will notice from the above that I used JOIN to link the two tables. Using a comma-list of table names went out of fashion about 21 years ago with the advent of the ANSI-92 join syntax.

`3`. Your query as shown cannot have worked. The `GROUP BY` clause belongs before the `HAVING` clause, not after. Having said that, point one above applies and you cannot compare the MAX value against the (base) column value anyway.

Comment: Thanks mate work perfect sorry I putted the comma-list was just a typing error

Answer (score 0):

This query can probably be simplified to:

```
select max(currencyname), max(currencysymbol), currencycode, max(exchangerate)
from currency group by currencycode
```

(- assuming there are no currencies that have never been used by any countries.)